# Can we send two people sms while checkout on shopify?

Tags: shopify, checkout, shopify-app, shopify-activemerchant, liquid-html

We have a product that is SMS text as a service. So when people purchase our product in Shopify, they get bite-sized educational text messages from us. The texts go to two people (a couple).

We need a way to capture phone numbers and send them each a transactional text once they've paid for their product. I understand that you can't capture 2 phone numbers via the official Shopify checkout page.

Is there any way we can send the same message while checkout in shopify?